# Should I use one or many filegroups for multiple FILESTREAM columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

I've used FILESTREAM columns before, but, oddly enough, I can only ever remember having one such column in an entire database before.

Now I'm looking at potentially having two, and they aren't related in any way - one would be a sort of "data bus" for holding file contents picked off a shared drop location before they're processed, and the other would hold preformatted reports prior to distribution.

Is the best practice here to use one file group for both columns (or, generally speaking, all FILESTREAM columns in a database)? Or should I create a separate filegroup for each of these?

Or, if there's no best practice, what factors should I be considering in my decision?